# Transfer data between ftl forms keycloak

Tags: java, authentication, keycloak

I've got custom auth flow with my auth provider. This provider also has its own custom form. After Username password login, i create my first form where user has to enter secret code(it's constant due to tests). After successful enter, i want to draw another form with just login, secret code and a button "Next", which will finish auth process.

The problem is, i don't know how to pass my secret code to the new form, and, more importantly, i don't know how to get it in my custom form.

```java
public class SecretCodeAuth implements Authenticator {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecretCodeAuth.class);
    @Override
    public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
        Response challenge = context.form().createForm("seccode.ftl");
        context.challenge(challenge);
    }

    @Override
    public void action(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
        String secretCode = context.getHttpRequest().getDecodedFormParameters().getFirst("seccode");
        String expectedCode = "555";

        if(secretCode==null||!secretCode.equals(expectedCode)){
            Response response = context.form()
                            .setError("badCode")
                                    .createForm("seccode.ftl");
            context.failureChallenge(AuthenticationFlowError.INVALID_CREDENTIALS, response);
            return;
        }

        context.getAuthenticationSession().setUserSessionNote("seccode", secretCode);
        Response challenge = context
                .form()
                .createForm("gonext.ftl");
        context.challenge(challenge);

        if("true".equals(context.getHttpRequest().getDecodedFormParameters().getFirst("confirmation")))
            context.success();
    }
}
```

And this is the second form code.

```
<#import "template.ftl" as layout>
<@layout.registrationLayout displayMessage=false; section>
    <#if section = "title">
        ${msg("loginTitle",realm.name)}
    <#elseif section = "header">
        Enter your secret code
    <#elseif section = "form">
        <form id="kc-totp-login-form" class="${properties.kcFormClass!}" action="${url.loginAction}" method="post">
            <div class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!}">
                <div class="${properties.kcLabelWrapperClass!}">
                    <label for="totp" class="${properties.kcLabelClass!}">Your secret code is:</label>
                </div>

                <div class="${properties.kcLabelWrapperClass!}">
                    <label for="totp" class="${properties.kcLabelClass!}">${user}</label>
                </div>

                <div class="${properties.kcInputWrapperClass!}">
                    <input id="totp" name="confirmation" type="hidden" class="${properties.kcInputClass!}" value="true" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!}">
                <div id="kc-form-options" class="${properties.kcFormOptionsClass!}">
                    <div class="${properties.kcFormOptionsWrapperClass!}">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="kc-form-buttons" class="${properties.kcFormButtonsClass!}">
                    <div class="${properties.kcFormButtonsWrapperClass!}">
                        <input class="${properties.kcButtonClass!} ${properties.kcButtonPrimaryClass!} ${properties.kcButtonLargeClass!}" name="login" id="kc-login" type="submit" value="Next" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </#if>
</@layout.registrationLayout>
```